# connect to only one schema in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am usning jBoss tools to generate POJO's from tables in my database but my database has many schemas so after configuration it took half of the day to show all the schemas.

Kindly let me know if there is any way to connect to the particular schema in database or any other property need to be defined in cfg file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the schema information present in your POJO classes which you have generated through the reverse Hibernate mechanism of your JBOSS tools.Just create different hibernate configuration files(cfg) and supply the schema information.Hibernate will configure it accordingly.

So all you need to do is create a separate cfg file for each schema with your same POJO files included in both config files